# Loading all items of a website on a single page

Tags: javascript, web-inspector

Think of a website that is supposed to show some items(e.g. products of a store). Such websites try to put a limited number of items(say 24) on a single page and show the remaining number of pages down at the bottom next to a "next" and a "previous" button that takes you to the next or previous page with other(24) items.
Now I'm looking for a way to load all these items on a single page all at once( without any next button).
IS there an easy way to do such a thing in inspect? Maybe there is an items-per-page variable which I can change its value.
Or even some lines of code in JS?
I should point out that I only have rudimentary JS skills.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on the implementation of the website.  You can check the Network panel of the developer tools in Chrome or Firefox to see what network requests are being sent, and try to identify the request that loads the items.  If you are lucky, the API will allow you to specify how many items you want to see.

Most websites should only request the items necessary for the current display, so there is no client-side JavaScript that could make them all be shown at once.  Loading only what is necessary saves time and internet bandwidth - imagine a store with hundreds or thousands of products, loading all of them at once would be catastrophic for page load times.